# Can't get the docker container to run in the build

Tags: postgresql, docker

I can't get the docker container to run in the build. My bundle is Django+Postgresql+Docker. I'm trying to run the command: "docker-compose build" and I get this error:

```
[3/6] RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev:
#6 0.262 /bin/sh: 1: apk: not found
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?
My docker file:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.8
# set work directory
WORKDIR /app
# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
# install dependencies
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
# running scripts
ENTRYPOINT ./runserver
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    volumes:
      - ./web/:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./web/.env.dev
      
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=shievtsovm2001
      - POSTGRES_DB=TSKHABD
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `python:3.8.8` is based on **"Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)** OS, so `apk` command does not work, `apk` is package manager for **Alpine Linux**.

You can simply check this by:

```
docker run -d --rm --name python python:3.8.8 tail -f /dev/null
```

Then:

```
docker exec -it python cat /etc/*release
```

So you should change `apk` to `apt-get`:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib gcc python3-dev musl-dev
```

Also check if these packages exist in Debian's repository in order to prevent not found errors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now the build lasts longer, but the error is still popping up https://ibb.co/1Lf6zMs

Comment: I think you should search for the packages you want in Debian repos, but I've edited my answer, check it again.